# Navigator not defined error when installing cypress version

Tags: cypress

Currently i am using cypress version 6.1.0.
I am trying to install latest version of cypress using `npm install --save-dev cypress@7.0.0`
It gives me below error.
Installation working fine up to version 6.9.1

```
ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at getChromeVersion (C:\Test222\node_modules\supports-color\browser.js:5:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Test222\node_modules\supports-color\browser.js:14:22)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Test222\node_modules\cypress\lib\util.js:41:23)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Test222\node_modules\cypress\index.js:9:14)
```

Comment: Can you try installing cypress 7.7.0 and check whether you get the same error or not ?

Comment: @AlapanDas Yes same error for 7.7.0 also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by reinstalling node.js